# jQuery 1.4 - ui Tabstrip with AJAX

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

So I have elected to play with jQuery 1.4 - and I am noticing something right off. This is not a real project ,so the code here should be taken with a grain of salt. I wrote it to reproduce the error.

Essentially, try to follow the jQuery UI Tabstrip AJAX loading example - you will get awkward results. For instance, the tabs link as ...

## ui-tabs-[object%20Object]

- Any idea what this is, and how to resolve it?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <link href="css/ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabstrip").tabs();
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="tabstrip">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.java.com">Java</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.asp.net/mvc">ASP.NET MVC</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.getfirefox">Mozilla FireFox</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the new release of jQueryUI on January 28th.  jQueryUI 1.7.2 expects certain behavior from jQuery that has been changed in 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.4.x is not compatible with jQueryUI 1.7.2
I run into the same problem with tabs that call ajax.
You can wait a few days until they release stable jQueryUI 1.8 or get the 1.8 RC2 now.
I've tested it with jQuery 1.4.2 and is working.